# Can I use generics to cast NSNumber to T in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, nsnumber

What I want

```
func safeGet<T>() -> T {
    let value = magic()
    if let typedValue = value as? T {
        return typedValue
    }
}
```

The reason this doesn't work is the fact that you can't do `<NSNumber> as Int` in swift

What do I put in the `<what do I put here?>` placeholder?

```
func safeGet<T>() -> T {
    let value = magic()
    if let typedValue = value as? NSNumber {
        return <what do I put here?>
    } else if let typedValue = value as? T {
        return typedValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried `T(typedValue)` and `typedValue as! T`

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to do it as a generic (at least without losing accuracy/information)  To get values out of `NSNumber` you'll want to be using type-specific functions like `doubleValue` and `boolValue`.  Doing it as a protocol and collection of extensions is probably a better approach.  That will also allow you to implement more useful type conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I did this to be able to get typed values from the dictionary in a way that throws errors. It's used like this

```
let name:String = dictionary.safeGet("name")
```

or

```
let name = dictionary.safeGet("name") as String`
```

The source code:

---

```
import Foundation

extension Dictionary {
    func safeGet<T>(key:Key) throws -> T {
        if let value = self[key] as? AnyObject {
            if let typedValue = value as? T {
                return typedValue
            }

            let typedValue: T? = parseNumber(value)
            if typedValue != nil {
                return typedValue!
            }

            let typeData = Mirror(reflecting: value)
            throw generateNSError(
                domain: "DictionaryError.WrongType",
                message: "Could not convert `\(key)` to `\(T.self)`, it was `\(typeData.subjectType)` and had the value `\(value)`"
            )
        } else {
            throw generateNSError(
                domain: "DictionaryError.MissingValue",
                message: "`\(key)` was not in dictionary. The dictionary was:\n\(self.description)"
            )
        }
    }

    private func parseNumber<T>(value: AnyObject) -> T? {
        if Int8.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.charValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return Int8(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if Int16.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.shortValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return Int16(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if Int32.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.longValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return Int32(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if Int64.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.longLongValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return Int64(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if UInt8.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.unsignedCharValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return UInt8(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if UInt16.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.unsignedShortValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return UInt16(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if UInt32.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.unsignedIntValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return UInt32(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if UInt64.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.unsignedLongLongValue as? T

            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return UInt64(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if Double.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.doubleValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return Double(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if Float.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.floatValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return Float(stringValue) as? T
            }
        } else if String.self == T.self {
            if let numericValue = value as? NSNumber {
                return numericValue.stringValue as? T
            } else if let stringValue = value as? String {
                return stringValue as? T
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    private func generateNSError(domain domain: String, message: String) -> NSError {
        return NSError(
            domain: domain,
            code: -1,
            userInfo: [
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message
            ])
    }
}
```